# Avoid repetition when selecting two columns of same table

Tags: matlab, boxplot

Each time I would like to work on two variables from the same table, I repeat the table's name for selecting them like in the following example:

```
boxplot(hospital.Weight, hospital.Sex)
```

This is a problem if the table's name changes because it requires two further changes to get it right.

Is there a more elegant way to avoid the repetition in the function call?

I tried:

```
boxplot(hospital( : , {'Weight', 'Sex'}))
```

But this returns the columns as tables and boxplot as far as I understand only takes vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create a dummy variable before generating your box plot so that you'd only have to change one line:

```
table_name = hospital; %this is the line you'd change if the table name changes
boxplot(table_name.Weight, table_name.Sex)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which alleviates and actually solves the problem. I still don't think it is beautiful code (maybe you agree - at least I hope you don't feel offended. `boxplot(Weight, Sex, table = hospital` would be syntactically much nicer for me.

Comment: Completely agree - I've rarely been accused of writing beautiful code. But I do appreciate and try to write code that is functional.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by @qbzenker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987372/2627163) is probably the best approach, but if you look for somthing else, you can use cell arrays for this:

```
C = table2cell(hospital(:,{'Weight','Sex'})); % this is the only place to change the table name
boxplot([C{:,1}],[C{:,2}])
```

If you want this in a nicer syntax, you can write a small function like:

```
function my_BoxPlot(T,F)
C = table2cell(T(:,F));
boxplot([C{:,1}],[C{:,2}])
end
```

and then call it with your preferred syntax:

```
subplot 121
my_BoxPlot(hospital,{'Weight','Sex'})
subplot 122
my_BoxPlot(hospital,{'Age','Sex'})
```

[image: 2-boxplots]

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki see my edit for creating more flexible syntax.